# The study of the convergence for a sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I would like to study both types of convergence for the sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots $ but I don't have the definition of the sequence so I can't get $X$ to compute $p(\{ |X_n - X|> \epsilon\})$.,

All what I have is the following $$p(X_n = \frac{1}{n}) = 1- \frac{1}{n^2} ~\text{and}~ p(X_n = n) =  \frac{1}{n^2} $$

How could I use these probabilities to evaluate if the sequence converges in probability and in quadratic mean?

Comment: *If* $X_n$ converges to anything under any definition then it will be $X=0$, so you should  consider $P( |X_n |> \epsilon)$ for large $n$ such as $n \gt \frac 1 \epsilon$, and $E[X_n ^2]$

Comment: I was actually making a suggestion for you to try yourself

Comment: What I was suggesting was that $\mathbb{P}[|X_n| > \epsilon] < \epsilon$ when $n> \frac1{\epsilon}$  and so $|X_n| \to 0$ in probability

Answer (score 1):

For convergence in probability, consider $X$ to be a constant random variable 0. Then you have $$\mathbb{P}[|X_n| > \epsilon] = \mathbb{P}[X_n = n, n > \epsilon] + \mathbb{P}[X_n = 1/n, 1/n > \epsilon] \leq \mathbb{P}[X_n = n] + \mathbb{P}[X_n = 1/n, 1/n > \epsilon]$$ Taking the limit of this expression will give 0 because $1/n^2 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and the limit of the second summand is 0 because $1/n \to 0$, giving the empty set as a limiting event.

For convergence in mean, note that $X = 0$ is no longer the limiting random variable because $$\mathbb{E}[X_n^2] = \frac{1}{n^2}(1 - \frac{1}{n^2}) + n^2\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n^2}(1 - \frac{1}{n^2}) + 1$$ which converges to 1 is $n \to \infty$. In computing the expectation we used the fact that $\frac{1}{n^2} + 1 - \frac{1}{n^2} = 1$, implying that $X_n$ takes only two values, $1/n$ and $n$.

Comment: We have $\mathbb{P}[X_n = 1/n, 1/n > \epsilon] = \mathbb{P}[\omega: X_n(\omega) = 1/n \cap 1/n > \epsilon]$. As $n \to \infty$, $\{\omega: X_n(\omega) = 1/n \cap 1/n > \epsilon\} \to \emptyset$.